# How does Schlage SecureKey Re-keying mechanism work?

Tags: product-recommendation, lock

[image]

[Here](http://consumer.schlage.com/Service-Support/Pages/securekey.aspx) is their consumer info. And [here](http://www.lockpicking101.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=47991&start=0) is an amateur teardown, although I can't tell from the pictures how the thing actually works. Does any one have any better powers explanation?

But beyond just being curious about the internal workings, the real question is how it compares to a regular pin-tumbler lock for security, smooth operation, longevity, etc?

Comment: Great question, I'm really curious about that also. Any mechanical engineer types out there got a good explanation?

Answer (score 10):

Good info here: http://www.lockwiki.com/index.php/Schlage_SecureKey

Comment: Wow, very informative site!

Comment: "Do not attempt to reset the key bitting with a blank reset key. Some wafers may not engage the guide pins and the lock will be non-functional." -- So does this mean that someone can walk up and intentionally jam the lock?

Comment: @Chris - I don't think so.  To get it into re-keying mode, you first need to insert the blue reset key that came with the lock (and is cut the same as the working keys) and turn it to 11 o'clock.